# php version 5.3.19 empty() issue

Tags: php

I have written a Joomla extension that counts traffic and I recently ran into a strange issue. I normally use

```
if (empty($items) AND ($bot == 0) AND ($iplock == 0))
```

and it worked fine until recently one of the uses sent me a message explaining that the system didn’t count unless he changed it to this.

```
$ei = empty($items) AND ($bot == 0) AND ($iplock == 0);
```

if ($ei == 1)

He is using PHP version 5.3.19 on his web server, can anyone explain why the second would work but the first wouldn't.

Thanks

Comment: The problem must lie somewhere else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two statements are **not** equal

Second statement is evaluated like this

`($ei = empty($items)) AND ($bot == 0) AND ($iplock == 0);`

because `$items` are empty, `$ei` get value `1`.

Do not use `AND` operator, it has lower precedence than `=`, use `&&`

Check [operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

Comment: Thanks what you said make sense.